# Empty vector characterstics in C++

Tags: c++, vector

The following function in the program searches for a target value in matrix and returns true if it is present else false and it gave error when a vector - `([])` or `([[]])` is passed i.e. whenever we passed an empty vector.

```
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int>>& matrix, int target) {
        int i = 0;        
        int m = matrix[0].size();        
        int n = matrix.size();        
        int j = m - 1;        
        if(n == 0 || m == 0)
            return false;
        if(target > matrix[n - 1][m - 1] || target < matrix[0][0])
            return false;
        while(j >= 0 && i < n){
            if(matrix[i][j] == target)
                return true;
            if(matrix[i][j] > target)
                j--;
            else
                i++;                        
            }
        return false;
    }
```

The error shown is Line 1038: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator>' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9

My error got rectified when I added initial line in my function as -

```
if(matrix.size() == 0 || matrix[0].size() == 0)
return false;
```

I didn't get why the first code gave an error if i can compare matrix.size() and matrix[0].size() with zero why can't I first store it in variable m and n and then compare it with zero.

Comment: If `matrix.size()` is zero, the initialisation of `m = matrix[0].size()` has undefined behaviour.    That comes before `m` and `n` are tested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this expression:

```
if (matrix.size() == 0 || matrix[0].size() == 0)
```

if `matrix` is empty, then the first condition before the `||` will evaluate to `true`, and the right hand side won't be evaluated, due to short circuiting.

In your code, you are indexing into `matrix[0]` unconditionally. If `matrix` is empty, this invokes undefined behavior.